# Shopify site loading JS files immediately

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I am attempting to optimize the speed on my Shopify site and I am told that I need to load external CSS files before external JS files. In the theme.liquid file, I made sure to move all external CSS files before the external JS files. However, when I load the website, it is showing several JS files at the very top of the opening `<head>` tag. I am completely unsure of where these files are being loaded from. How can I force these files to load after the external files?

[Inspector HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPWXE.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
================================================== -->
  
  <title>
    {{ page_title }}{% if current_tags %} &ndash; tagged "{{ current_tags | join: ', ' }}"{% endif %}{% if current_page != 1 %} &ndash; Page {{ current_page }}{% endif %}{% unless page_title contains shop.name %} &ndash; {{ shop.name }}{% endunless %}
  </title>
  {% if page_description %}
  <meta name="description" content="{{ page_description | escape }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}" />

  {% include 'social-media-meta-tags' %}
  
  <!-- CSS
================================================== -->

  {{ 'stylesheet.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {{ 'font-awesome.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {{ 'queries.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {{ "fonts.css"  | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {{ 'bold.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {{ 'custom.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  {{ 'rewards.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
{% include 'bold-product' with product, hide_action: 'header' %}

  {% include 'google-fonts' %}
  <!--[if LTE IE 8]>
  {{ 'gridlock.ie.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}  
  <![endif]--> 
    <!--[if IE 7]>
  {{ 'font-awesome-ie7.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
  <![endif]-->

  {{ 'bold.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
 
  
  <!-- JS Script
================================================== -->
  {% include 'limespot-global-head-includes' %}
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ 'favicon.png' | asset_url }}">
  

  {% if template contains 'customers' %}
  {{ "shopify_common.js" | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ "customer_area.js"  | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}
  {% endif %}

  {{ content_for_header }}



  
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function() {  
      $('.prod-container').matchHeight();

    });
  </script>   
  
<!-- Bold D&H //theme -->
{% if product.metafields.inventory.ShappifyHidden == "true" %} <meta name="robots" content="noindex"> {% endif %}
<!-- // end theme D&H -->
  
<!-- Start of thegldshop Zendesk Widget script -->
<script>/*<![CDATA[*/window.zEmbed||function(e,t){var n,o,d,i,s,a=[],r=document.createElement("iframe");window.zEmbed=function(){a.push(arguments)},window.zE=window.zE||window.zEmbed,r.src="javascript:false",r.title="",r.role="presentation",(r.frameElement||r).style.cssText="display: none",d=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),d=d[d.length-1],d.parentNode.insertBefore(r,d),i=r.contentWindow,s=i.document;try{o=s}catch(c){n=document.domain,r.src='javascript:var d=document.open();d.domain="'+n+'";void(0);',o=s}o.open()._l=function(){var o=this.createElement("script");n&&(this.domain=n),o.id="js-iframe-async",o.src=e,this.t=+new Date,this.zendeskHost=t,this.zEQueue=a,this.body.appendChild(o)},o.write('<body onload="document._l();">'),o.close()}("https://assets.zendesk.com/embeddable_framework/main.js","thegldshop.zendesk.com");
/*]]>*/</script>
<!-- End of thegldshop Zendesk Widget script -->


    {{ 'bold-helper-functions.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
 
  
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '903638969718533');
fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=903638969718533&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
  
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="HBLWBeNWSyVpfKi1kphn9N-pawBjK09WMSV2F7MmVKU" />
  
<!-- Start Alexa Certify Javascript -->
<script type="text/javascript">
_atrk_opts = { atrk_acct:"V9iOn1QolK10cv", domain:"thegldshop.com",dynamic: true};
(function() { var as = document.createElement('script'); as.type = 'text/javascript'; as.async = true; as.src = "https://d31qbv1cthcecs.cloudfront.net/atrk.js"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(as, s); })();
</script>
<noscript><img src="https://d5nxst8fruw4z.cloudfront.net/atrk.gif?account=V9iOn1QolK10cv" style="display:none" height="1" width="1" alt="" /></noscript>
<!-- End Alexa Certify Javascript -->  
 
<!-- Start Crazy Egg Script -->  
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");
var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
a.src=document.location.protocol+"//script.crazyegg.com/pages/scripts/0055/5395.js?"+Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/3600000);
a.async=true;a.type="text/javascript";b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}, 1);
</script>  
<!-- End Crazy Egg Script -->
  
  
<!-- Bing Tracking Code -->
<script>(function(w,d,t,r,u){var f,n,i;w[u]=w[u]||[],f=function(){var o={ti:"5527824"};o.q=w[u],w[u]=new UET(o),w[u].push("pageLoad")},n=d.createElement(t),n.src=r,n.async=1,n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=function(){var s=this.readyState;s&&s!=="loaded"&&s!=="complete"||(f(),n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=null)},i=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],i.parentNode.insertBefore(n,i)})(window,document,"script","//bat.bing.com/bat.js","uetq");</script><noscript><img src="//bat.bing.com/action/0?ti=5527824&Ver=2" height="0" width="0" style="display:none; visibility: hidden;" /></noscript>
<!-- End Bing Tracking Code -->  
  
  
  
  
  <!-- JS External
================================================== -->


  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  {% assign custom = all_products.custom-set %}
  {% assign custom_handle = 'custom-set' %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var customImage = "{{ custom | img_url: 'small' }}";
    var customHandle = "{{ custom_handle }}";
  </script>

  {{ 'theme.js' | asset_url | script_tag }} 
  {{ 'option_selection.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}  
  {{ 'handlebars.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {{ 'api.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}  
  {{ 'jquery.fs.shifter.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}

  {% if template == 'index' %}
  {{ 'instafeed.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
  {% endif %}
  
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  
</head>
```

Comment: Please show the code of the top of your `theme.liquid` file. Where is `{{ content_for_header }}` in relation to your CSS/JS file loads?

Comment: I'm also curious why there's a `<div>` within your `<head>` tag?

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure where the <div> comes from either. I updated the code above with all of my header code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch these are being injected by 3rd party plugins, but either way, it's not going to help your response times much because the scripts are all being loaded asynchronously. In your screenshot, you'll notice all of those script tags have an async attribute:

```
<script src="//somwhereovertherainbow.com" async></script>
```

If you use the async attribute, you are saying: I don't want the browser to stop what it's doing while it's downloading this script. I know that this script doesn't really depend on anything being ready in the DOM when it runs and it also doesn't need to be run in any particular order.

This is actually more optimal than running the script at the bottom of the `<head />` since it delays execution until the DOM is finished loading.

Now to address the bigger issue.

Loading CSS before JavaScript isn't going to improve your load time because everything that's in the head will always block whats in the body until its completely loaded and parsed.

What will improve your load time is moving JS to the bottom of the body or using the async attribute.

Here's an example of an optimized page:

```
<html>

<head>
  // We put styles at the top so everything will render
  // without having to parse additional styles
  <link rel="stylesheet" ... />
  <style></style>

  // If you put any JavaScript up here, it will load and run 
  // before anything in the <body />
  //
  // So we avoid this...
  //
  // <script src="..."></script>
  // Since it'll block rendering to download and parse the JavaScript
  //
  // or this...
  //
  // <script>window.onload = function () { }</script>
  // Since it'll block rendering to parse the JS.

  // You can load scripts asynchronously, however, in which case, the script will download and run after the body has been loaded
  <script src="..." async></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Once the head is done the body renders -->
<div id="status">Loading..</div>
<!-- People often put scripts at the bottom of the page to delay execution as well -->

<script>document.getElementById('status').textContent = 'Loaded!'</script>
</body>
</html>
```